# Bluetooth Emulators/Simulators

Tags: c#, c, bluetooth

What are the best bluetooth emulators/simulators?

I have a project for a security course, and I chose bluetooth as my topic.

I need to create an encryption algorithm using a bluetooth simulator and test them. I have already searched for the best emulators, and the results were Google's Android emulator, and NS2.

Are there any alternatives to these?

The languages I prefer to program with are C, C++, and C#.

Java is also not a problem but I would prefer an emulator that would let me use any of the above languages.

Answer (score -1):

Just download Microsoft's Visual Studio 2010 for **Windows Phone 7**. There's even a free Express version.